# Looping eventListener?

Tags: javascript

Hi you guys I'm new to JS and programming in general. Just started learning and was wondering out of curiosity is there a way to loop through click eventListener. So Each time I click on my h1 header with a title id I get the innerHTML changed kind of like a infinite shuffle ?

```
const element = document.getElementById("title");


element.addEventListener("click", function(){
    element.innerHTML = "Cool Right?";

    element.addEventListener("click", function(){
        element.innerHTML = "SoundPad";
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Create an array with the string you would like to cycle (`strings`)
2. Create an integer in which we will hold the current shown index (`i`)
3. Add `click` listener in which we will:

   1. Check if our current index is at the last value, if so, cycle to `0`
   2. Set `element.innerHTML` to the index of the array
   3. Bump the index

```js
const element = document.getElementById("title");
const strings = [ 'Hello', 'How', 'Are', 'You', '?' ];
let i = 0;

element.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (i === strings.length) i = 0;
    element.innerHTML = strings[i];
    i++;
});
```

```html
<h1 id='title'>Starting Title</h1>
```

---

Instead off the 3 lines, we can simplify this in many ways:

1. Fancy one-liner using the same logic as above

   ```
   element.addEventListener("click", () => element.innerHTML = strings[(i === (strings.length - 1)) ? (i = 0) : ++i]);
   ```
2. Using the [modulo operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) (`%`) to set `i`

   ```js
   element.addEventListener("click", () => {
        i = (i + 1) % strings.length
        element.innerHTML = strings[i];
   });
   ```

Comment: Alternatively `i = (i + 1) % strings.length`  if you want to remove the if-statement.

Comment: Thought I'd keep it simple for OP.

Comment: Perfect, Thank you so much for your help :)